# TypeError: $(...).SetHeight is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

I'm writing a fluid layout for my website and I use jQuery to set the DIVs height and width.
In the SetHeight function I give the wanted height as the function's first parameter than I subtract the margins and apply the new height.

```
function SetHeight(height){
    var outer = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    var current = $(this).height();
    var margin = o-c;
    height = height-margin;
    $(this).css("height",height);   
};
```

Here's the code which triggers the error message:

```
var h = $(window).height();
$("#Slider").SetHeight(h-260).removeClass("mobile");
```

I'm using *$(document).ready* and *$(window).resize* with a timer to check if I need to resize any DIV.

What I've missed?

Comment: SetHeight() is not a jquery method. To set it as jquery's method, use: `$.fn.SetHeight = function(){/*your code*/ return this;})` Then you can use: `$("#Slider").SetHeight(...)` FYI, by convention, should be setHeight() not SetHeight()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined a function, but you're using it like a method on the jQuery object.

if you do this:

```
function f(param1, param2){
    // code
}
```

you need to use it like this:

```
f(div, 4);
```

If you want to use it like you are, you need to do something like this:

```
$.fn.SetHeight = function(param1, param2){
    // code
}
```

So you might want this:

```
function SetHeight(height){
    var outer = this.outerHeight(true);
    var current = this.height();
    var margin = outer-current;
    height = height-margin;
    this.css("height",height);
    return this;  // to allow chaining
};
$.fn.SetHeight = SetHeight;  // add as a jQuery method
```

Then you can use your code:

```
$("#Slider").SetHeight(h-260).removeClass("mobile");
```

Which you can use as you did in your example.

Notice that `this` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it like: `$(this)`. And you should return `this` at the end to support chaining - like calling `.removeClass("mobile")` at the end.

---

See also: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/

Comment: Thanks the advice! I'm kind of newbie in jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that error because no `Jquery object` has a function like `SetHeight()` You should change your function definition and function call like below to achieve your need.

Try,

```
function SetHeight(xElement,height){
    var outer = xElement.outerHeight(true);
    var current = xElement.height();
    var margin = o-c;
    height = height-margin;
    xElement.css("height",height);   

   return xElement;
};
```

Function call,

```
var h = $(window).height();
SetHeight($("#Slider"),h-260).removeClass("mobile");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SetHeight` function is not part of the jQuery object's prototype.

Make it one, or have it take a jQuery or DOM object as the first argument.